# Bash command-line in vi mode - command-line find/replace

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, vi

New to linux :-)

In my .bashrc I have `set -o vi`.
That way when I'm in the terminal I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>{</kbd> and then use VI commands to navigate, edit and search the command history.

One thing I cannot figure out is how to find and replace.  Let's say for example, I have the following command `cp /abc/*.src /def/*.src`.  How can I find/replace `src` with `trg`?

To clarify, I'm NOT in the VI/VIM editor.  I'm on the command-line.  For example, on the command-line to access the last command, i can do the following:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>{</kbd>
<kbd>k</kbd>

Then to append to the end of command I can do:

<kbd>$</kbd>
<kbd>a</kbd>

How can I change my command using find/replace on the command-line.

Thanks

Comment: So what for all discussion about `vi` (in title, tags, ...) as time as you want  find/replace on the history command-line?

Comment: @hba I'm just wondering if you got the answer or not. BTW, it would be better if you highlight 'Bash in vi mode' in your question title :)

Comment: @Drake - done...no I still don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

The command for replacing a string with another in vi editor is

```
  %s/FindMe/ReplaceME/g
```

for more information on usage :  [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)